# Core Java Print

Tags: java, string, int

Please respond in case there can be any other or further explanation for the same?

```
System.out.println("abc"+1+2); // which gives output as abc12
System.out.println(1+2+"abc"); // which gives output as 3abc..
```

From the above code,

The control is considered from the left to right direction so considering the 1st sysout, when it encounters 1 treats it as string and when encounters 2 treats it as string and makes it 12

While in the second case, it treats 1 as int while it comes to 2 which is again an int, adds it to 1 and makes it 3.

Comment: You're right.  A `String` plus an `int` is a `String` - this is concatenation.  An `int` plus an `int` is an `int` - this is addition.

Comment: `+` is used as a concatenation operator when it found first occurence of  `String`.

Comment: IMHO, it is not related with the implementation of `print/println`. The method receives the already concatened String and displays it.

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to java

```
 String + int => String  
 int + int => int
```

so in the first statement,

```
System.out.println("abc"+1+2);
```

"abc" is a string object, if you add primitives to string it'll become string in the same way 1 added to the "abc" and become "abc1" the same for 2 also it just concatenates to the string then finally printed it as "abc12".

```
System.out.println(1+2+"abc");
```

In this case the same thing happens but the first two values are int so it'll added like normal int variables and become a string value after 3 added to "abc" then printed as "3abc".

Answer (score 0):

In first syso

```
System.out.println("abc"+1+2);
```

it treats it as a string and concatinate it with previous values and shows the answer and in second syso

```
System.out.println(1+2+"abc");
```

it take first two number as int and then add it and then it will print the sum and then concatinate that with the string. if we want to add first syso numbers so we must put these numbers in barcket so then the compiler with take these numbers as integer and then print there sum and concatinate with string.

```
System.out.println("abc"+(1+2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The results that you observe are certainly related to both operator precedence and order of evaluation. Since all operators are of the same precedence, operators are evaluated in order from left to right.

In the first expression, all operators have the same precedence, because they're the same operator: +, and so the first operation is evaluated. Since it involves a `String`, it is `String` concatenation, and the result is a `String` and it stays `String` for the following +.

In the second expression, all operators have the same precedence, because they're the same operator: +, and so the first operation is evaluated. Since it involves an `int`, it is an `int` addition, and the result is an `int` and it stays `int` for the following +.

Answer (score 0):

just try it

```
System.out.println((1+2)+"abc");
```

output :

3abc

See docs:http://www.coderanch.com/t/539770/java/java/System-println-confusion-quotation-marks